# What do you call the converse of an invariant subspace of an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, definition, jordan-normal-form, invariant-subspace

**Question**. I am looking for the concept converse to invariance: what do we call a set $W$, such that $$T(w) \in W \implies w \in W ?\tag{1}$$

I feel there was a word for this, but I can't recall it, maybe something related to "absorbent" or $\alpha$-limit... A suitable adjective, noun, a convenient phrase (or an explanation why they don't exist) count as a good answer.

**Context**. $W\subseteq V$ is called an invariant set or subspace of a linear operator $T:V\to V$ if $$T(W)\subseteq W.$$ Equivalently, $W$ is called $T$-invariant if $w \in W \implies T(w) \in W$.

For simplicity, assume that $\dim V = n < \infty$ and $T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix. If $T$ is invertible, then
$$T(w) \in W \implies w \in W,$$
becomes, after substituting $w=T^{-1}(v)$,
$$v \in W \implies T^{-1}(v) \in W, \tag{4}$$
which is equivalent to saying $ W \text{ is } T^{-1}\text{-invariant}$ and writing
$$T^{-1}(W) \subseteq W.\tag{5}$$

If $T$ is not invertible, we can still use (4) and (5) by defining $T^{-1}$ as the pre-image of $T$. If I am not mistaken, this is also equivalent to a linear (e.g. orthogonal) complement of $W$ being $T$-invariant,
$$ T(W^{\perp})\subseteq W^{\perp}.$$ However, I find all these characterisations awkward and am looking for a better and more expressive word.

This question came up when I was thinking about Schur decomposition, Jordan normal form and generalised eigenspaces. An eigenspace is an invariant subspace in which $T$ is "spherical". Thinking about the invariance of eigenspaces does not get us far, because the invariance does not address generalised eigenvectors (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition)). Similarly to a regular eigenspace, a generalised eigenspace is $T$-invariant, that, is we cannot *leave* it. But importantly, we cannot *enter* it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elchanan Solomon's lightning-fast answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4452765) is acknowledged. However, more can be said.

> A subspace $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathbb{C}^n $ is called **coinvariant** for the transformation $A: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$: if there is an $A$-invariant *direct complement* to $\mathcal{M}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n $.

> A subspace $\mathcal{M}\subset \mathbb{C}^n $ is called **orthogonally coinvariant** for the transformation $A: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$: if the *orthogonal complement*  $\mathcal{M}^\perp$ to $\mathcal{M}$ is $A$-invariant.

These definitions are found on pp 105 and 108 of

- Israel Gohberg, Peter Lancaster, and Leiba Rodman. *Invariant Subspaces of Matrices with Applications*. SIAM (Classics in applied mathematics),  2006.  https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898719093

As the title suggests, the book is an awesome source on this topic and includes clear examples and relevant results. Here is a close quote of two of them, which illustrate the relation to the adjoint $A^*$:

> **Proposition 3.1.2**. A subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is $A$-coinvariant iff its orthogonal complement $\mathcal{M}^\perp$ is $A^*$-coinvariant.

> **Proposition 3.1.3**. A subspace $\mathcal{M}$ is *orthogonally* $A$-coinvariant iff it is $A^*$-invariant.

Answer (score 3):

By taking the contrapositive, this is equivalent to $w \in W^{C} \to T(w) \in W^{C}$, so $W^{C}$ is $T$-invariant. Perhaps $W$ should then be called *co-invariant*?

Comment: Yes! I think _co-invariant_ is also used [here](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Linear_Systems_and_Control/rSSOUFgPxecC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22co-invariant+subspace%22&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover) in exactly the same sense.